# Is there a way to add each result to a row of the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm working on a method to annotate a text and currently building a function to add each text and its pos to a row on the dataframe.

Text:   pos :

apple   PROPN
be      AUX
look    VERB

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Text', 'pos'])

def annotate(text):
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
    doc = nlp(text)

    for token in doc:
        print(token.text, token.pos_) 
        df = df.append({'Text' : 'token.text', 'pos' : 'token.pos_'},  ignore_index = True)

annotate('Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion')
```

Comment: it's unclear what your question is. does this code work as you expect?

Comment: Well, the code works but the creation of the dataframe doesn't. I want to create a dataframe of two columns text and pos which at every itteration it will get 'token.text' in text and 'token.pos_' in pos, inside the loop for. @AbbeGijly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try collecting the data, THEN creating the dataframe.  In general that will run more efficiently than appending rows to an existing dataframe:

```
def annotate(text):
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
    doc = nlp(text)

    rows = []
    for token in doc:
        print(token.text, token.pos_)
        rows.append([token.text, token.pos])
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['Text', 'pos'])
    return df
```

then call it using:

```
df = annotate('Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice ! , it solved my problem. @AbbeGijly